# Determining the the Length of a Date Range Overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a constraint that I have two date ranges. One of them will never change it is a measurement period (Date Range A). I need to try and find if the second Date range (Date Range B) Overlaps with A for a length of at least 6 months. What would be the best way to go about this?

I have considered trying to compare the start and end dates of the two ranges in different ways depending on how the two intersect, but have yet to hit upon a solid methodology.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Added tag for the database

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what's the database so I worked an example in PostgreSQL:

```
create table a (
  since date,
  upto date
);

insert into a (since, upto) values ('2017-01-01', '2017-10-25');

create table b (
  since date,
  upto date
);

insert into b (since, upto) values ('2017-04-24', '2018-01-15');
insert into b (since, upto) values ('2017-06-01', '2018-01-15');
insert into b (since, upto) values ('2016-08-15', '2017-10-04');

select a.*, b.*
  from a, b
  where a.upto > b.since + interval '6 month' and a.since < b.since
     or b.upto > a.since + interval '6 month' and b.since < a.since
```

Result:

```
since          upto           since          upto           
------------------------------------------------------------
2017-01-01     2017-10-25     2017-04-24     2018-01-15     
2017-01-01     2017-10-25     2016-08-15     2017-10-04
```